# Trying to create a table in excel via VBA and OLEDB

Tags: vba, excel, oledb, adodb

I am trying to create a table (tab) in Excel using VBA with ADODB. Could you tell me where I am going wrong?

I get an error at `comm.Execute` after the `comm.CommandText = "create table [temptable]([AA] VARCHAR(40));"` line:

> Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'temptable'.

Adding a $ at the end of the table name or a # at the beginning does not seem to help.

```
Sub sqlquery2()
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim conn As String
  Dim conObj As ADODB.Connection
  Dim comm As ADODB.Command
  Dim fileName As String

  Set conObj = New ADODB.Connection
  Set comm = New ADODB.Command

  fileName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
  conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
       "Data Source=" & fileName & ";" & _
       "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 XML"

  conObj.ConnectionString = conn
  conObj.Open

  comm.ActiveConnection = conObj
  comm.CommandType = adCmdText
  On Error Resume Next
  comm.CommandText = "DROP TABLE [temptable];"
  comm.Execute
  On Error GoTo 0
  comm.CommandText = "create table [temptable]([AA] VARCHAR(40));"
  comm.Execute
  comm.CommandText = "insert into [temptable] select [A] from [SQL_Test$];"
  comm.Execute

  conObj.Close
End Sub
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Does the `temptable` exist while you are trying to drop it? This looks rather like sql question not vba one.

Comment: Which line does the error occur on - will address @avb question

Comment: Thanks. That's not what's throwing the error. It's the create table command that's causing the problem. So the error is actually thrown on the second comm.Execute

Comment: Could you comment the lines with `On Error...` and try it? there should be an error  dropping the table...

Comment: Sure. Then I get "Table 'temptable' does not exist". But that part is only there to remove the table if it is there from a previous run. That's why I have the error handling around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it on a closed workbook.

I've had this problem with an open workbook. It disappeared when I did it on a closed workbook. It was also crashing telling me the table (worksheet) did not exist when the wbk was open. The worksheet did exist. This problem also disappeared when I queried a closed wb.

Comment: Thanks. I am using vba called from a button in the same workbook so that's tricky.

Comment: I've had this problem with an open workbook. It disappeared when I did it on a closed workbook. It was also crashing telling me the table (worksheet) did not exist when the wbk was open. The worksheet did exist. This problem also disappeared when I queried a closed wbk.

Comment: Aha! Thank you that is helping. Now I get "Circular reference caused by alias 'AA'" - but a big step forward. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure but this may be because column AA already exists and you're not using column headers.

Comment: Yes, that last error was just me being silly. So now it's working. Thank you so much!